# How should I use @Configurable to automatically assemble beans into common objects in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

What I need now is to have an ordinary abstract class and its subclasses. These beans need to be injected into the abstract class. They are just ordinary objects, but have some ioc-managed beans to perform operations. I need to serialize them into redis. Save it, and then take it out of redis to deserialize, but when taken out, these beans become null. I originally wanted to manually inject them one by one, but they may have nesting problems. I can’t do that. It is very troublesome to configure beans without recursively, so I looked for a lot of solutions, I found the `@Configurable` annotation, but when I want to use it, there is no complete document, very difficult, need to configure `aspectJ`, `LTW`, `aspectj-maven -plugin`, you also need to use `-javaagent:/path/to/spring-instrument.jar` when restarting, I am completely confused, I don’t know how to use it, it’s too much trouble, and I can’t find a complete one available The `@Configurable` use case, I don't want to use `-javaagent:/path/to/spring-instrument.jar` at all, I found many articles similar to these, and even mentioned `bytebuddy`. But they are not comprehensive and can’t be used, which makes me a headache

- https://blog.csdn.net/crazypandariy/article/details/108172434#comments_15058136
- [Spring boot @Configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833052/spring-boot-configurable)
- [how to reattach singleton Spring beans upon deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471835/how-to-reattach-singleton-spring-beans-upon-deserialization#)

I want to use it like this

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
@JsonSubTypes(
        value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SinglePipeLink.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SequencePipeLink.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SplitFlowPipeLink.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(LoopPipeLink.class)
        })
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME, preConstruction = true)
public abstract class BasePipeLink implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5308571029549664750L;
    protected String copyFrom;

    @Resource @JsonIgnore protected transient RedisService redisService;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a Maven project on GitHub. This question does not contain enough information to answer it.

Comment: Friendly reminder: Please provide more information, as requested. Thank you.

Comment: I got it, thank you

Comment: You are answering after almost one year, and then the answer is cryptic. Can anyone be so lazy? You got **what?**

Comment: Sorry, I changed my job and forgot about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually enabled LTW through Bytebuddy

```java
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get access to an instrumentation instance
        Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        // Activate AspectJ weaver
        Agent.agentmain("", instrumentation);
        // Save instrumentation instance for later use
        InstrumentationSavingAgent.agentmain("", instrumentation);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify for others who might not understand this automatically: You are not using Byte Buddy (BB) itself here, but a small tool library called `byte-buddy-agent`, which is completely independent of BB and helps people who want to dynamically attach an agent without `-javaagent` to do so, hiding the complexity. The library is small and helpful, but it is another dependency for your project.

Comment: Just for reference, the AspectJ weaver since 1.8.7 has the capability to be dynamically attached to a JVM, see the [read-me](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html). Because it is the first contribution I ever made to AspectJ, I can still remember.  BTW, I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66947304/1082681). But of course, your approach with the extra tool library is also valid and needs less boiler-plate code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is just to use aspect, but because I don't want to use Java-Agent before starting the command, I solve it via byte-buddy-agent, the core problem is still in the enabled LTW to use it., And the results I have given simplified aspectj, thank you for your answer.