# How to get access to WEB-INF/lib/ jars?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, war, aspectj

I have Gradle project with **Spring Boot** and **AspectJ**.

Want to load `aspectjweaver` and `spring-instrument` javaagents dynamically and directly from WEB-INF/libs (where Spring Boot locate all dependencies)

**Gradle dependencies:**

[image]

**AgentLoader:**

```java
public class AgentLoader {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgentLoader.class);

public static void loadJavaAgent() {
    if (!isAspectJAgentLoaded()) {
        LOGGER.warn("Aspect agent was not loaded!");
    }
}

public static boolean isAspectJAgentLoaded() {
    try {
        Agent.getInstrumentation();
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        return false;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Dynamically load AspectJAgent");
        return dynamicallyLoadAspectJAgent();
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean dynamicallyLoadAspectJAgent() {
    String nameOfRunningVM = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    int p = nameOfRunningVM.indexOf('@');
    String pid = nameOfRunningVM.substring(0, p);
    try {
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
        String jarFilePath = AgentLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/libs/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar").toString();
        vm.loadAgent(jarFilePath);
        jarFilePath = AgentLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/libs/spring-instrument-5.3.2.jar").toString();
        vm.loadAgent(jarFilePath);
        vm.detach();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception while attaching agent", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

But found out that return value of `getResource()` in `null`

What is the best solution to handle this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Interesting question. Please help me a little bit, so I can help you. Just post a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, so I can reproduce the problem. I am not a Spring Boot or Gradle user, I am a Maven guy. But if I have a working project setup, I can look into your class-loader problem with AspectJ. I need to see how the uber JAR is packaged, which class loader is used while executing your agent loader class and how/when that one is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2024-01-12:** For another reason, I revisited this topic and changed the code a bit, utilising the tiny `byte-buddy-agent` library as a helper to determine the running JVM's process ID and either self-attach or, if on JDK 9+ that option is deactivated, spawn another helper JVM and attach the agent from there. I made sure that the solution still works on JDK 8, but also on 9+ (tested up to JDK 21).

I removed the extra options listed below in the original answer from my Maven POM, i.e. no more `includeSystemScope` and no more system-scoped dependency on *tools.jar* from the old JDK 8. Instead, only this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
  <version>1.14.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The new code looks like this:

```java
public class AgentLoader {
  public static boolean dynamicallyLoadAspectJ() {
    try {
      ClassLoader classLoader = AgentLoader.class.getClassLoader();
      System.out.println("AgentLoader classloader = " + classLoader);
      final String pid = ByteBuddyAgent.ProcessProvider.ForCurrentVm.INSTANCE.resolve();
      try (InputStream nestedJar = Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar"))) {
        File targetFile = new File("aspectjweaver.jar");
        Files.copy(nestedJar, targetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        ByteBuddyAgent.attach(targetFile, pid);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Exception while attaching agent");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I also decided to use `System.err` directly instead of using a logger instance here, to avoid loading lots of classes before the aspect weaver is active. Once they are loaded, the weaver cannot change them anymore later.

---

Nikita, today is your lucky day. I just had a moment and was curious how to make my code snippet from https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html, which obviously you found before, work in the context of Spring Boot. I just used my Maven Spring Boot playground project. Depending on which Java version you are using, you either need to make sure that tools.jar from JDK 8 is defined as a system-scoped dependency and also copied into the executable Spring uber JAR, or you need to make sure that the Java attach API is activated in Java 9+. Here is what I did for Java 8:

**Maven:**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<!-- (...) -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>spring.aop.DemoApplication</mainClass>
    <!-- Important for tools.jar on Java 8 -->
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `<includeSystemScope>` option is necessary because otherwise Boot does not know how to find the attach API classes. Just do something equivalent in Gradle and you should be fine.

**Java:**

You need to know that in order to attach an agent, it **must** be a file on the file system, not just any resource or input stream. This is how the attach API works. So unfortunately, you have to copy it from the uber JAR to the file system first. Here is how you do it:

```java
public static boolean dynamicallyLoadAspectJAgent() {
  String nameOfRunningVM = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
  int p = nameOfRunningVM.indexOf('@');
  String pid = nameOfRunningVM.substring(0, p);
  try {
    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
    ClassLoader classLoader = AgentLoader.class.getClassLoader();

    try (InputStream nestedJar = Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar"))) {
      File targetFile = new File("aspectjweaver.jar");
      java.nio.file.Files.copy(nestedJar, targetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      vm.loadAgent(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    vm.detach();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception while attaching agent", e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Besides, in my case the files were unter `BOOT-INF/lib`, not `WEB-INF/lib`.

---

**Update:** You said you have this follow-up problem somewhere along the line (reformatted for readability):

```
failed to access class
  org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer
from class
  org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj
(
  org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer is in
    unnamed module of
    loader 'app';
  org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj is in
    unnamed module of
    loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @3e9b1010
)
at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:108)
```

This means that `Aj` is unable to find its own inner class `Aj.WeaverContainer`. This indicates that they are loaded at different points in time and in different classloaders. When remote-debugging into my sample Boot application starting from an executable JAR, I see that the application classloader is actually the `LaunchedURLClassLoader`'s parent, i.e. the class loaded in the parent is trying to access another class only available to its child classloader, which is impossible in Java. It only works the other way around.

Maybe it helps not to import and reference AspectJ weaver classes from inside the agent loader. Try commenting out the `loadJavaAgent()` and `isAspectJAgentLoaded()` methods and also remove `import org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent;`. Then in your application just directly call `AgentLoader.dynamicallyLoadAspectJAgent()` and see if this helps. I have some more aces up my sleeves with regard to agent loading, but let's keep it as simple as possible first.

Comment: Thanks kriegaex a lot. It's wonderful that I solved my problem in same way you presented. We think lonely :)

Comment: It works for now, but I started receiving strange error:
`failed to access class org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer from class org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj (org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj$WeaverContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @3e9b1010)
 at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:108)`

Comment: That is a typical classloader problem. The AspectJ weaver is loaded in classloader A, but referenced by classes in loader B. I might be able to help you, but not without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So now it is your turn. Extract a minimal reproducer project and publish it on GitHub, so I can take a look. I do not wish to speculate or guess. Thanks.

Comment: I happened to click on this question again and just noticed that `Aj` is unable to find its own inner class `Aj.WeaverContainer`. This indicates that they are loaded at different points in time and in different classloaders. See the answer update I am going to write in a few minutes.

Comment: Removing `import org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent` really works, thank you for the help. But which aces did you mean? :)

Comment: Please let us not make my answer and this discussion any longer if your problem is solved. SO is a Q/A site, not a discussion forum. I am happy it works for you now. 

Comment: @kriegaex you "should" create a git repo with all this nice examples of yours

Comment: Please note the updated sample code and description for JDKs 8-21, using `byte-buddy-agent` library for making agent attachment easier.